# Loop/Iterate through date range while inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

So I have data being imported into a table (let's call is RAWDATA) in the following format:

```
EMPID  | STARTDATE  | ENDDATE    | TOTALHOURS | TOTALWAGES
ABC123 | 01-01-2013 | 01-28-2013 | 160.0      | 1800.00
XYZ987 | 01-01-2013 | 01-31-2013 | 200.0      | 2500.00
```

I need to take that data, and put it in a different table (EMPDATA) in the following format:

```
EMPID  | DATE       | HOURS | WAGES
ABC123 | 01-01-2013 | 5.71  | 64.29
ABC123 | 01-02-2013 | 5.71  | 64.29
ABC123 | 01-03-2013 | 5.71  | 64.29
...... | .......... | ....  | .....
XYZ987 | 01-01-2013 | 6.45  | 80.66
XYZ987 | 01-02-2013 | 6.45  | 80.66
XYZ987 | 01-03-2013 | 6.45  | 80.66
...... | .......... | ....  | .....
```

My thought is to do a DATEDIFF between STARTDATE and ENDDATE to figure out how many days (in this case: 28) to spread the hours and wages over, then for each day, insert a row that contains the average hours and wages worked per day. This will all be done with a trigger on the RAWDATA table. I'm just not sure how to iterate from STARTDATE to ENDDATE in a trigger.

EDIT:
I should also state that the data being imported does not always have the same start/end date for each row. I have updated the first table example to indicate this.

Comment: Do you need to handle just one row, or multiple rows?

Comment: Multiple rows. I have updated the question

Comment: And what is the maximum date range you need to support? 31 days, or longer? And is this SQL Server 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012?

Comment: @D.R. The demo included in my answer also shows multiple rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a `date` table and use a `JOIN`.
2. Calculate days between `startdate` and `enddate`
3. Divide `totalhours` and `totalwages` by calculated days.

Here's my solution:

```
SELECT a.empid, b.dd AS date, 
  CAST(a.totalhours AS decimal) / (DATEDIFF(day, startdate, enddate) + 1) AS hours,
  CAST(a.totalwages AS decimal) / (DATEDIFF(day, startdate, enddate) + 1) AS wages
FROM wages a
INNER JOIN dates b ON dd BETWEEN a.startdate AND a.enddate
```

**Result**

```
|  EMPID |       DATE |         HOURS |          WAGES |
--------------------------------------------------------
| ABC123 | 2013-01-01 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-02 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-03 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-04 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-05 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-06 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-07 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-08 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-09 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-10 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-11 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-12 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-13 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-14 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-15 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-16 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-17 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-18 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-19 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-20 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-21 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-22 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-23 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-24 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-25 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-26 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-27 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
| ABC123 | 2013-01-28 | 5.71428571428 | 64.28571428571 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/115b9/1)

Comment: But I'm inserting the data into another table, not just generating a different result set

Comment: @D.R. Please see [INSERT with SELECT syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). That should help do the job.

Comment: @PolishPrince The question specifically asked for an INSERT statement.

Comment: By far the best solution. triggers need high performat code, not iteration or recursion. I'd upvote a million times if I could.

Comment: @swasheck, sdlect into willnot work in a trigger, it only works if the table does not exist.  YOu need to add insert to the top of this with your table name and fields. The author of this is right, we shouldn't do your work for you.

Comment: @swasheck SELECT INTO will create a new table. Not bad, but should be mentioned. And yeah, thanks for the syntax, I missed the whole SQL Server part.

Comment: i need to have coffee before i start commenting/answering on SO

Comment: @PolishPrince I'd also like to thank you for showing me SQL Fiddle! That's a great site!

Comment: Any solution where a date table is not required?

Comment: @D.R. Date table is really your **best** solution. Just take a quick peak at the performance charts in [this article](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3) .

Comment: @D.R. that depends, what is your specific objection to a date table?

Comment: @AaronBertrand FWIW, you converted me to a date table. I owe you a beer.

Comment: I consulted with the dba and he is OK with a date table so I have used your solution! Thanks!

Comment: I assume for a trigger, the only change I need to make is to add the INSERT part and JOIN it on the "INSERTED" table as well so it only does it for rows that have been inserted

Comment: Here's a weird one. I put the sample data into the database, and I'm getting 6.93 and $67.67 for avghours and avgwages for row 1 and 7.67 and $84.33 as the averages for row 2! This is bizarre...going to go through it with a fine-tooth comb!

Comment: Darn order of operations! I forgot the parenthesis around the DATEDIFF(day,startdate,enddate)+1 so it was dividing by the wrong number, then adding one! all fixed now!

Comment: @D.R. Sounds to me like the `datediff` is getting miscalculated. If you can, throw the sample data into a fiddle with the query you're using.

Comment: Good call on the date table. Saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL Server 2005 and higher, you can use a `Recursive CTE` for this to create your dynamic date ranges (vs using a lookup table).  This uses `GROUP BY` on the empid field and assumes a single row for each empid:

```
WITH RecCTE AS (
  SELECT empid, startdate
  FROM rawdata
  UNION ALL
  SELECT R.empid, DATEADD(day,1,R.startdate)
  FROM RecCTE R JOIN rawdata RD ON R.startdate < RD.enddate
  )
INSERT INTO EMPDATA 
SELECT R.EmpId, R.StartDate, T.TotalHours/R2.cnt, T.TotalWages/R2.cnt
FROM RecCTE R
  JOIN (SELECT empid, totalhours, totalwages
        FROM rawdata
       ) T ON R.empid = T.empid
  JOIN (SELECT EmpID, COUNT(*) cnt 
        FROM RecCTE 
        GROUP BY EmpID) R2 ON R.EmpID=R2.EmpId
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d3ca/2)

There might be a way to make this a little more efficient, but this should get you going in the right direction.  For example, you could use a `COUNT` `OVER` Function to return the count vs the subquery:

```
WITH RecCTE AS (
  SELECT empid, startdate
  FROM rawdata
  UNION ALL
  SELECT R.empid, DATEADD(day,1,R.startdate)
  FROM RecCTE R JOIN rawdata RD ON R.startdate < RD.enddate
  )
INSERT INTO EMPDATA 
SELECT R.EmpId, R.StartDate, 
    T.TotalHours/COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY R.EmpId), 
    T.TotalWages/COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY R.EmpId)
FROM RecCTE R
  JOIN (SELECT empid, totalhours, totalwages
        FROM rawdata
       ) T ON R.empid = T.empid
ORDER BY R.StartDate
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was able to use PolishPrince's answer! I appreciate the help though

Comment: @D.R. -- not a problem -- glad they could help.  Just wanted to offer an alternative to having to create and maintain a separate dates table.  Best regards!

Comment: What is everyone's big objection to "having to create and maintain a separate dates table"? Is it really that hard to build a table, once, populate it, once, and not have to maintain it at all (until our calendar changes)? Is the concern performance? (Such a table will be tiny, and if you reference it enough, it will always be in memory.) I don't comprehend why such a useful table is met with such resistance.

Comment: @AaronBertrand -- I have no issue with the accepted answer (I gave it a +1).  I was trying to supply an alternative (as OP asked for).  In my consulting career, there have been several instances/clients where I can NOT create a new table (permissions for example), and therefore must utilize other means to solve the problem (in this case, a recursive CTE).  Best regards.

Comment: @sgeddes right, the question wasn't directed at you, a little more general than that. People constantly scoff at the suggestion to create a table and I guess I don't like to see that scoffing encouraged. :-)

Comment: Seeing how useful a date table can be, you almost wish MSSQL and/or other DB software included a system-wide table for dates (or some function that would act as the same)