# Using Between Statement and Cycle Through Months -- Indicate whether month falls within between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2008-r2

Basically I have a list of names with start and end dates. Since I'm currently unable to redesign the previous designer's process for a more simplistic operation, I need to find a way to loop through a list of names and for each month that falls in between the start and end date update a table with that month/year to true.

Here's the current way it's being done in Access:

```
SELECT 
    dbo_Elig.MEM_ID, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#12/1/2011# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#11/1/2011#,1,0)) AS mm201111, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#1/1/2012# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#12/1/2011#,1,0)) AS mm201112, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#2/1/2012# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#1/1/2012#,1,0)) AS mm201201, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#3/1/2012# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#2/1/2012#,1,0)) AS mm201202, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#4/1/2012# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#3/1/2012#,1,0)) AS mm201203, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#5/1/2012# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#4/1/2012#,1,0)) AS mm201204, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#6/1/2012# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#5/1/2012#,1,0)) AS mm201205, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#7/1/2012# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#6/1/2012#,1,0)) AS mm201206, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#8/1/2012# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#7/1/2012#,1,0)) AS mm201207, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#9/1/2012# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#8/1/2012#,1,0)) AS mm201208, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#10/1/2012# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#9/1/2012#,1,0)) AS mm201209, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#11/1/2012# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#10/1/2012#,1,0)) AS mm201210, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#12/1/2012# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#11/1/2012#,1,0)) AS mm201211, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#1/1/2013# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#12/1/2012#,1,0)) AS mm201212, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#2/1/2013# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#1/1/2013#,1,0)) AS mm201301, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#3/1/2013# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#2/1/2013#,1,0)) AS mm201302, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#4/1/2013# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#3/1/2013#,1,0)) AS mm201303, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#5/1/2013# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#4/1/2013#,1,0)) AS mm201304, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#6/1/2013# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#5/1/2013#,1,0)) AS mm201305, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#7/1/2013# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#6/1/2013#,1,0)) AS mm201306, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#8/1/2013# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#7/1/2013#,1,0)) AS mm201307, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#9/1/2013# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#8/1/2013#,1,0)) AS mm201308, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#10/1/2013# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#9/1/2013#,1,0)) AS mm201309, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#11/1/2013# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#10/1/2013#,1,0)) AS mm201310, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#12/1/2013# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#11/1/2013#,1,0)) AS mm201311, 
    Max(IIf([BEGIN_COVERAGE_DATE]<#1/1/2014# And [END_COVERAGE_DATE]>=#12/1/2013#,1,0)) AS mm201312 
INTO [t_mm11-13] 
FROM dbo_Elig 
GROUP BY dbo_Elig.MEM_ID;
```

I'm trying to avoid writing the case statements in SQL to mimic this process.

This [Loop/Iterate through date range while inserting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705169/loop-iterate-through-date-range-while-inserting) article has a version that seems right for PL/SQL, but I'm not sure how to adapt it to work for SQL Server 2008 R2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use cursors if you really want do go down the iterative route, but that statement would work in t-sql too with some minor modifications. Or you could build the statement using dynamic sql.

Comment: is it always going to be from `201111` to `201312`?   If not, what determines the number of month columns?

Comment: According to the previous owner, the issue was that Access was unable to accommodate 2011-current data and so it was split up into separate sections -- hence the 201111-201312. The date range is a rolling 5 year period, but we just haven't had the client log enough for the from date to change yet.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid CASE statement as it is a direct replacement for your IIF?